# Laravel 4 - New and I'm stuck already

Tags: php, controller, laravel, laravel-4, restful-architecture

I'm new to Laravel 4 and I'm stuck already... I can't seem to get my head around routes.

I keep getting this error, when I go to the following URL account/welcome/Scott/UK:

```
    Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Routing\Controller::missingMethod()
```

This is what is in my routes file:

```
    Route::controller('account', 'AccountController');
```

And this is in my controller:

```
public function action_welcome($name, $place)
{

      echo "Welcome to {$place}, {$name}!";

}
```

Can anyone shed any light on this? It must be something really simple.

Comment: Are you accessing it like http://example.com/welcome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proper syntax for actions in a Laravel 4 RESTful Controller:

```
class GenericController extends Controller {

    public function getWelcome($name, $place)
    {

          echo "Welcome to {$place}, {$name}!";

    }

    public function postLogin()
    {

          ...

    }

}
```

You can see if it's right by executing

```
php artisan routes
```